# Can't ping / access docker host on 172.17.0.1 from inside a container

Tags: docker

My docker host listens on 172.17.0.1.

I can curl it from the host machine, but when I curl the same ip/port from within the container I get timeout.

I can ping anything from withing the container but I can't access the host.

What am I missing ?

Container is Jenkins image run by this command:

```
docker run -d --name jenkins -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:2.222.3
```

Running curl on the host:

> curl http://172.17.0.1:2375 {"message":"page not found"}

Running curl from withing the docker will time out.

> curl http://172.17.0.1:2375 curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1
>   port 2375: Connection timed out

Comment: How is the firewall configured on the host? Please include the `iptables -S` output in your question.

Comment: Additionally, exposing the docker socket to the network makes it trivial to hack the server. Anyone with network access, whether an unprivileged local user or anyone remote, can run `docker -H tcp://172.17.0.1:2375 run -it --rm --privileged --pid host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i bash` to get root. Either give access to the socket file with group permissions and a volume mount, or setup mTLS. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Comment: @BMitch - you were right. iptables blocked the access. you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's typically because iptables on the host is blocking access from the docker networks. You can look at `iptables -S` or `iptables -nvL` to see your current rules.

---

That said, if you do open up the docker API, you need to be careful about who can access that API. Using port 2375 typically means you have not configured mTLS, see [docker's guide for setting up mTLS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/). This means anyone with access to the port can submit API calls, which means an unprivileged local user, or any other container, has the ability to get root on your host. In your case, that's as easy as:

```
docker -H tcp://172.17.0.1:2375 run -it --rm --privileged --pid host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i bash
```

The recommended solution is to either use DinD to run the docker engine inside of a container, or to share the docker socket as a file/volume mount with the appropriate UID/GID access to the file. That ensures only that container has access to the docker engine rather than all users and any container running on the host. To handle the UID/GID access issues with files mounted in a volume, I've done this specifically for Jenkins images in my [jenkins-docker](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker) repo, and there's a more generic solution in my [fix-perms script in my docker-base repo](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base/blob/master/bin/fix-perms).

Answer (score 1):

@BMitch - I've figure it out - but your got it right as well (should you post it as an answer I'll accept and delete mine) 
the iptables blocked the access. 
once I opened it - it worked as expected.